# Xcode8.3で作成したプロジェクトでWindowControllerが登録されない

Tags: xcode, objective-c, macos, xcode8

お世話になります。

題記の通りXcode 8.3.2 を使って作成したプロジェクトで、DocumentクラスにWindowControllerで作成したウィンドウを追加しようと、下記のようなコードを書きましたが、NSLog文で参照したDocumentのwindowControllersにはwc2しか入っていませんでした。

何故、同じWindowControllerの（サブクラス）のインスタンスなのに、片方は`WindowControllers`に追加され、もう片方は追加されないのでしょうか？
デバッガーでステップ実行しながら確認したところ、両方ともインスタンスは生成されていてnilを渡している可能性はありません。

`HogeWindowController`のインスタンスを`addWindowControllers:`に追加する作法が増えたのでしょうか？

ご存じの方、原因がわかる方、回答を是非お願いします。

```
- (void) makeWindowControllers {
    HogeWindowController *wc1 = [[HogeWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"HogeWindowController"];
    wc1.document = self;

    NSWindowController *wc2 = [[NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"Document Window Controller"];

    // Override to return the Storyboard file name of the document.
    [self addWindowController:wc1];
    [self addWindowController:wc2];


    NSLog(@"%@", wc1);
    NSLog(@"%@", wc2);
    NSLog(@"%@", self.windowControllers);
}
```

出力結果

```
2017-04-21 18:03:23.619170+0900 Charleston[83983:832625] <HogeWindowController: 0x600000086400>
2017-04-21 18:03:26.545108+0900 Charleston[83983:832625] <NSWindowController: 0x618000085a50>
2017-04-21 18:03:28.271030+0900 Charleston[83983:832625] (
    "<NSWindowController: 0x618000085a50>"
)
```

Comment: AppleのNSWindowControllerのドキュメントに 「documentプロパティに値を入れるな」とあります。 `wc1.document = self`を削除するとどうなりますか？

Comment: wc.document = selfの行を削除したところ、無事Windowが開きました。ありがとうございます。その後、wc1.documentを確認したところ、selfが入っていたので、wc1.documentを設定するのはaddWindowControllerの仕事の様ですね。最初からそうで勘違いしていたのか、途中から変わったのか自信がありませんが、以前はそれでできていたので大変困惑していました。ありがとうございます。回答として記述頂ければ承認させて頂きたいと思います。